# Converting a class to a generic interface

Tags: c#-4.0

I've got the following interfaces:

```
public interface ISendableMessage
{
}
```

and

```
public interface IMessageSenderStrategy<T> where T: class, ISendableMessage
{
    void Send(T message);
}
```

For testing, I then fave the following classes that derive from the above:

```
public class FakeMessage: ISendableMessage
{
}
```

and

```
public class FakeMessageStrategy: IMessageSenderStrategy<FakeMessage>
{
    public void Send(FakeMessage message)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

}

I'm then in my unit tests trying to add a fake message to a `List<IMessageSenderStrategy<IMessageSender>>` and even with an explicit conversion, this is not working as I'd expect--the cast is returning null!

Does anyone know how I can convert a `FakeMessageStrategy` to an `IMessageSenderStrategy<ISendableMessage>` for storage in a list. I could make the `IMessageSenderStrategy` non-generic, but if I can avoid it I'd rather not as there will be several of these throughout the project.

I've tries using the in keyword on the generic interface parameter with no luck.

Comment: Please take care while formatting a question. Badly formatted questions get ignored at best

Comment: Where is your testing and casting code? And how do you expect a Message to become a Strategy? Your Strategy classes *use* Messages, they don't inherit from them. Shouldn't you be using a `List<ISendableMessage>` ?

Comment: Can you share the (relevant part) of the unit test too? Also a definition of `IMessageSender`, an implementation of it and the part in the unit test where these are used would be nice. Until that time, my first guess would be to change the list type to `List<IMessageSenderStrategy<ISendableMessage>>` and continure from there.

Comment: Hi, 
The test is below, I'm casting as you'll see but the fs variable is always null, this should work given that FakeMessage derives from ISendable message, or at least that is what I thought!            

List<IMessageSenderStrategy<ISendableMessage>> strategies =new List<IMessageSenderStrategy<ISendableMessage>>();
            var fs = new FakeMessageStrategy() as IMessageSenderStrategy<ISendableMessage>;
            strategies.Add(fs);
How can I solve/get round this?
Cheers
Sean.